# Disable volume controls on external speaker connected through usb sound card

Tags: ubuntu, pulseaudio

I have a USB sound card (Avantree Leaf) connected to a PC with Ubuntu 19.10 and a Dockin D-Fine speaker connected via AptX to the sound card.

In Ubuntu 18.10 everything worked kind of ok - volume control on the PC and on the speaker were independent and when I changed volume on speaker it didn't affect PC volume.

In 19.10 it was "improved" and now when I change volume on speaker, volume on PC changes as well. But it's buggy:

- volume control remained independent, just if I press "+" volume control is increased on the speaker and on the PC at the same time
- sometimes when I press "+" on the speaker it descreases volume on the PC

So, the question:

How can I disable changing PC volume from the speaker?

It's a standard Ubuntu 19.10 installation, so it uses PulseAudio.

```
$ cat /proc/asound/cards | grep Leaf
 2 [Leaf           ]: USB-Audio - Avantree Leaf
                      Avantree Leaf at usb-0000:00:1d.7-5.2, full speed
```

```
$ amixer -c 2
Simple mixer control 'PCM',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback 0 - 15
  Mono: Playback 0 [0%] [-15.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Mic',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cvolume-joined
  Capture channels: Mono
  Limits: Capture 0 - 31
  Mono: Capture 24 [77%] [24.00dB]
```

```
$ pacmd dump
### Configuration dump generated at Sun Jan 12 16:42:59 2020

load-module module-device-restore
load-module module-stream-restore
load-module module-card-restore
load-module module-augment-properties
load-module module-switch-on-port-available
load-module module-switch-on-connect
load-module module-udev-detect
load-module module-bluetooth-policy
load-module module-bluetooth-discover
load-module module-bluez5-discover
load-module module-native-protocol-unix
load-module module-default-device-restore
load-module module-rescue-streams
load-module module-always-sink
load-module module-intended-roles
load-module module-suspend-on-idle
load-module module-console-kit
load-module module-systemd-login
load-module module-position-event-sounds
load-module module-role-cork
load-module module-snap-policy
load-module module-filter-heuristics
load-module module-filter-apply
load-module module-alsa-card device_id="1" name="pci-0000_0f_00.1" card_name="alsa_card.pci-0000_0f_00.1" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes avoid_resampling=no card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1"
load-module module-alsa-card device_id="0" name="pci-0000_00_1b.0" card_name="alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes avoid_resampling=no card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1"
load-module module-x11-publish display=:1
load-module module-x11-cork-request display=:1
load-module module-x11-xsmp display=:1 session_manager=local/dasha-HP-Z600-Workstation:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/2419,unix/dasha-HP-Z600-Workstation:/tmp/.ICE-unix/2419
load-module module-alsa-card device_id="2" name="usb-0a12_Avantree_Leaf-00" card_name="alsa_card.usb-0a12_Avantree_Leaf-00" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes avoid_resampling=no card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1"
load-module module-cli-protocol-unix

set-sink-volume alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo 0x725a
set-sink-mute alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo no
suspend-sink alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo yes
set-sink-volume alsa_output.usb-0a12_Avantree_Leaf-00.iec958-stereo 0x570c
set-sink-mute alsa_output.usb-0a12_Avantree_Leaf-00.iec958-stereo no
suspend-sink alsa_output.usb-0a12_Avantree_Leaf-00.iec958-stereo yes

set-source-volume alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor 0x10000
set-source-mute alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor no
suspend-source alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor yes
set-source-volume alsa_output.usb-0a12_Avantree_Leaf-00.iec958-stereo.monitor 0x10000
set-source-mute alsa_output.usb-0a12_Avantree_Leaf-00.iec958-stereo.monitor no
suspend-source alsa_output.usb-0a12_Avantree_Leaf-00.iec958-stereo.monitor yes
set-source-volume alsa_input.usb-0a12_Avantree_Leaf-00.mono-fallback 0xc3b1
set-source-mute alsa_input.usb-0a12_Avantree_Leaf-00.mono-fallback no
suspend-source alsa_input.usb-0a12_Avantree_Leaf-00.mono-fallback yes

set-card-profile alsa_card.pci-0000_0f_00.1 off
set-card-profile alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0 output:analog-stereo
set-card-profile alsa_card.usb-0a12_Avantree_Leaf-00 output:iec958-stereo+input:mono-fallback

set-default-sink alsa_output.usb-0a12_Avantree_Leaf-00.iec958-stereo
set-default-source alsa_input.usb-0a12_Avantree_Leaf-00.mono-fallback

### EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: scroll down to where I talk about udev and add the rule to your udev config if you are configuring an avantree dg60 like I have. Otherwise, you'll need to follow the below steps to figure out the specific values to use in the udev rule as it is very hardware specific.

I also have an avantree device and also found this annoying. It turns out it does the volume control by registering an HID to send the media key events.

I tried it on Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04, but the process should be very similar for other operating systems and sound cards that have this potentially annoying feature.

Look at lsusb first to get the bus/device numbers for your avantree/usb sound card. Here's the relevant section on my own, yours will be different:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 003 Device 009: ID 0a12:1004 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd
```

If you're not sure which vendor/product ID yours is, check dmesg's output when you plug it in/remove it, looking for entries like "usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0a12, idProduct=1004, bcdDevice=30.83".

Take a look at "lsusb -t" to see what it has registered. Here is the relevant section of mine:

```
...
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 480M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 9, If 0, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 9, If 1, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 9, If 2, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 9, If 3, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
...
```

See, at Bus 03: Port 1 => Port 2: dev 9, interface 3, it has registered an HID. Next, check the sysfs entry at /sys/bus/usb/devices/[bus]-[port]. For me, that is /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-2:

```
$ ls -l /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-2/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root     0 Jun  2 19:14 3-2:1.0
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root     0 Jun  2 19:14 3-2:1.1
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root     0 Jun  2 19:14 3-2:1.2
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root     0 Jun  2 19:14 3-2:1.3
...
```

We can see the interface 3 in there (the 1.3) from the lsusb -t. List the files in there...

```
$ ls -1 /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-2/3-2:1.3 
0003:0A12:1004.0036
authorized
bAlternateSetting
bInterfaceClass
bInterfaceNumber
bInterfaceProtocol
bInterfaceSubClass
bNumEndpoints
driver
ep_81
modalias
power
subsystem
supports_autosuspend
uevent
usbmisc
```

You will see an "authorized" attribute assigned to that HID which defaults to "1". Simply setting that to "0" will temporarily fix it:

```
$ echo 0 > /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-2/3-2:1.3/authorized
```

The effect should be immediate. However, you probably want it to automatically do that from now on. That is possible by writing a udev rule:

```
ACTION=="add", ATTR{idVendor}=="0a12", ATTR{idProduct}=="1004", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo 0 > /sys$DEVPATH/`basename $DEVPATH`:1.3/authorized'"
```

Put the above rule in /etc/udev/rules.d/99-avantree.rules and make sure it has permissions 644 and user:group=root:root and reload the rules by doing "udevadm control --reload-rules" and next time the device is inserted, that "authorized" attribute should be set to 0.

The RUN script gets the $DEVPATH (which for me contains /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:28:00.3/usb3/3-2. The /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-2 is a symlink to this path, except $DEVPATH is missing the /sys) and prefixes /sys and suffixes the 1-4 in the $DEVPATH variable, and adds the 1.3.

This fix might not be 100% stable as I'm not totally sure of the udev matching and paths and such, but it seems to be working for me when I try different usb ports.

Comment: I can confirm that this solution works with my Avantree DG60. It kept on picking up random volume control commands from my headset (Sony W1000-XM3), especially if I moved out of the antenna range and it (presumably) switched to a different transmission protocol. 

My vendor ID is also 0a12 and product ID 1004.